# at least one signature is invalid in pdf signing

Tags: pdf, itext, signing

when I am signing a PDF using IText with e-token then signed pdf is  showing'at least one signature is invalid' in Acrobat Adobe Reader.I am using valid e-token. Below is the code for signing Pdf.

> ```
> //path of destination file    
> String destFile = "D://sign_test.pdf";  
> // load key store    
> KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");       
> ks.load(null, "password".toCharArray());    
> Enumeration enumeration = ks.aliases();    
> String alias = null;    
> while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()){  
> alias = (String)enumeration.nextElement();  
> if(alias.equalsIgnoreCase("alias of the certificate"))// to get specific certificate from keystore  
> break;  
> }  
> PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, "password".toCharArray());  Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);  
> PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceFile);  
> FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destFile);  
> PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');  
> PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper .getSignatureAppearance();  
> appearance.setReason("I've written this.");  
> appearance.setLocation("Foobar");  
> appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(72, 732, 144,      780),1,"first");  
> ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256", "SunMSCAPI");    
> ExternalDigest digest = new ProviderDigest("SunMSCAPI");  
> MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null,    null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);    
> stamper.close();
> ```

Comment: Please share a sample signed PDF for analysis.

Comment: please find the pdf here: http://demo.lotusprocure.in/sign_test.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The reason is: Your chosen certificate is invalid***

### Details

If you look at what Acrobat Adobe Reader says exactly, you find in the signature panel:

[image: Signature panel]

Thus, the signature itself is mathematically correct:

> Document has not been modified since this signature was applied

but the problem is in your certificate:

> Signer's certificate is invalid

If you click further through to the certificate view you'll see

[image: Certificate viewer]

So the reason why the signer's certificate is invalid is:

> Not valid for usage.

Indeed, you see the intended usage above:

> Encrypt Keys

For creating signatures, you need *Signing* or *Non-Repudiation*.

So you merely have to select a certificate which is intended for signing.

Comment: thanks it solved my problem. the problem was two certificate having same alias name in e-token.